# OSGi `uses` constraint violation, even though compatible exporters exist

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'm seeing this error when I try to install a bundle in my OSGi container:

```
Error executing command: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource com.example.myproject [com.example.myproject/5.0.0.SNAPSHOT] because it is exposed to package 'javax.jms' from resources com.example.resource1 [com.example.resource1/2.0.1] and com.example.resource2 [com.example.resource2/1.1.1] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  com.example.myproject [com.example.myproject/5.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.jms
  com.example.resource1 [com.example.resource1/2.0.1]

Chain 2:
  com.example.myproject [com.example.myproject/5.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.example.intermediary)(version>=7.2.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.example.intermediary; uses:=javax.jms
  com.example.intermediary [com.example.intermediary/7.2.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.jms
  com.example.resource2 [com.example.resource2/1.1.1]
```

As far as I can tell, the package version exported by com.example.resource1 can satisfy both chains. So why wouldn't it just use resource1 in both places?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because there is no guarantee that loading a class from `javax.jms` it will end up only at bundle `com.example.resource1` (which exports the only valid version of the package). So within a certain "wiring" state of a bundle (every resolved package it imports at runtime, transitively), there should never be packages in different versions.

This is called **Class space consistency** and is defined in [OSGi Core 7 - 3.7.6 Package Constraints](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#i3127019).

Once the core JVM has learned to differentiate classes in different versions, this restriction might not be needed anymore - as long as the consequences are made clear there is control over it.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm saying is that it is possible, given the bundles that exist here, to have class space consistency, by simply not using com.example.resource2 at all. The higher-versioned exporter can satisfy both dependency chains without conflict. So why doesn't the container do that?

Comment: That's probably a timing issue at deployment time. If both, `com.example.resource1` and `com.example.resource2` are available for the resolver when `com.example.intermediary` gets resolved, it will be wired to the higher version, unless there is another version constraint in-place that doesn't allow that higher major version to be used. If a Bundle refresh of `com.example.intermediary` doesn't solve the issue, then you have other requirements in either bundle that needs to be resolved differently. I hope you didn't package and export `javax.jms` yourself?